# How to use lambda functions in f strings and return the value conditionally?

Tags: python-3.x, lambda, string-formatting, f-string

I've googled a lot but can't seem to find anything about this problem, or maybe since I'm a noob I'm not searching the correct keywords. I did find one question but it was using an f-string inside a lambda function which is the exact opposite of what I need.

So I have a counter flag called `tc` which checks if the sum of two numbers exceeds a certain predefined constant. The counter flag works fine and gets `1` or `0` correctly. The thing I can't do is the next part of the program.
I want to directly check the condition and return it in an f-string.
Till now I've been able to make this.

```
timE = f"({(lambda x: x = 'next' if tc==1 else x = 'same')} day)"
print(timE)
```

What I get is

```
File "<fstring>", line 1
    ((lambda x: x = 'next' if tc==1 else x = 'same'))
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What I need is if `tc` is 1 then the lambda function should return `next` else `same`.
And then the final result I need is either `(next day)` or `(same day)`.

I did try some other thing which does not give me an error but is giving me something else.

```
timE = f"({(lambda : 'next' if tc==1 else 'same')} day)"
```

The output I'm getting here is

```
03:08 AM, (<function add_time.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7fe5b4660dc0> day)
```

I know what I'm trying to do is somehow in someway possible in some hacky way, but I can't seem to find it. 
Any help is appreciated

Comment: thats very dirty way of doing very simple thing but still if you want to do it then this will do. `timE = f"({(lambda x: 'next' if x==1 else 'same')(tc)} day)"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just this? You do not need a lambda here.

```
timE = f"({'next' if tc==1 else 'same'} day)"
```